# How to handle statusCode =302 after a post request

Tags: redirect, post, node-red

I am using http request (post) to an api endpoint.

I pass the correct parameters for authentication on `msg.payload {"username:"xxx","password":"password"}`. The server return the `statusCode = 302` and I can't read the set-cookie header.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: 302 is basically redirection of url.

Comment: You need to include a lot more information here.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the node-red-contrib-https 1.0.0. I changed to the HTTP Request Node that comes with node-red, import the tls certificate and everything works.